# Resolving Flow type errors

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am writing an extension to Array, and trying to incorporate typechecking with Flow, but have an error that I can't seem to work out.

The function Sum below has an optional argument of transformer, and if transformer is undefined, gives it a default.  It then loops through the array and, if the element is a number, applies the transformer function and adds the result to sum.

Flow is giving the warning that "Function cannot be called on possible undefined value".  I thought that the checks that transformer is defined and is a function should mitigate this? What is the best solution?

```
// @flow

export function Sum(transformer : ?(a : number) => number) : number {

    const transformerIsUndefined = typeof(transformer) === "undefined";

    if (!transformerIsUndefined && typeof(transformer) !== "function") {
        throw "Transform argument must be a function";
    }

    if (transformerIsUndefined) {
        transformer = item => item;
    }

    let i : number = 0;
    let sum : number = 0;
    while (i < this.length) {
        if (typeof(this[i]) === "number") {
            sum += transformer(this[i]);
        } else {
            throw "Non-numerical element in the array.";
        }
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by changing the argument to required, and providing a default in the function signature:

```
export function Sum(transformer : (a : number) => number = item => item) : number {
    ...
}
```

I would still be interested in other takes on this.